# Voigt Limiting Distributions (How to calculate)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I wanted to verify some specific parameter values on the Wikipedia page for the Voigt distribution. It should have been a simple exercise but it seems that either I am lacking in a correct understanding of how to obtain those specific parameter values or those listed on the website are incorrect.

The description of the Voigt distribution and the information pertinent to my particular question can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile). The specific values that I attempted to verify are those listed in the first and second graphs of the distribution. Under the first graph, we have the following text:

"Plot of the centered Voigt profile for four cases. Each case has a full width at half-maximum of very nearly 3.6. The black and red profiles are the limiting cases of the Gaussian (γ =0) and the Lorentzian (σ =0) profiles respectively."

The picture of the plot is below. I am only interested in the limiting cases (black and red).

I tried to verify the numbers 1.53 and 1.8 numerically by writing a small Matlab program that should build a Voigt distribution. Since the Voigt distribution is the convolution of Normal and Cauchy distributions (i.e. we add those random variables to each other), we should then be able to take the resulting data points and estimate its parameters for the Normal and Cauchy distributions, respectively. The snippet of code is below. Notice that the snippet is attempting to obtain the 1.8 value:

```
N = 1000000;  % Number of samples

r1 = random('Normal',0, 0.01,[N 1]); 

% Create a Cauchy distribution by the ratio of two
% N(0,1) random variables. I know this is just 1 
% specific case. 

r2 = random('Normal',0, 1,[N 1]);
r3 = random('Normal',0, 1,[N 1]);
 
r4 = r2./r3;
 
% Addition of Normal and Cauchy R.V. is convolution
% of the distributions.
Q = r1+r4;

%Determine parameters for the normal distribution
fitdist(Q,'Normal')

% Determine parameter for the Cauchy distribution
median(abs(Q))
```

I'd appreciate any insights the community could provide me with. I feel as if I am missing some piece of understanding.

Thanks again!

[image: Plot of the Voigt Distribution with specific values]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using simulation to verify the parameter values for a FWHM of $3.6$.  The [formulas at the bottom of the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile#The_width_of_the_Voigt_profile) are clear for the limiting cases of Gaussian and Lorentzian profiles:  $$f_G = 2 \sigma \sqrt{2 \log 2}, \\ f_L = 2\gamma.$$  Setting $f_G = 3.6$ yields $$\sigma = \frac{9}{5 \sqrt{2 \log 2}} \approx 1.52878,$$ and $\gamma = 1.8$ exactly.  This is where those parameter values come from, and these formulae for FWHM can be derived from the exact Gaussian/Lorentzian densities in each case.

Moreover, you would not need to generate realizations from a Voigt density if all you really want are those limiting cases.  It's only when we are **not** dealing with a limiting case where the FWHM formula becomes inexact, and this is where the calculation could benefit from a simulation based approach.  The method would involve generating a large number of realizations of the sum of a normal and a Cauchy random variable for some scale parameters $\sigma, \gamma$, then compute a quantile of that data set.  Specifically, for a given bin width $\delta > 0$, you would compute the number of realizations in $[-\delta/2, \delta/2]$, and then find the bin(s) for which there are half as many observations.  This would not give a very precise estimate, unfortunately.

Analytically, the peak (mode) of the Voigt density is given by

$$f_V(0) = \frac{2e^{\gamma^2/(2\sigma^2)}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} \Phi(-\gamma/\sigma),$$ where $$\Phi(z) = \int_{x=-\infty}^z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.  Then the half maximum is simply $\text{HM} = f_V(0)/2$.  You would then numerically solve $$f_V(x_{\text{HM}}) = \text{HM},$$ which will yield two solutions that are equal in magnitude but opposite in sign.  This can be done using recursive bisection or some other iterative approach.  The FWHM will then be $2|x_{\text{HM}}|$.  For instance, using *Mathematica*, I get
$${\text {FWHM}}(\sigma = 1, \gamma = 1.8) \approx 4.81509.$$